# OpenAI Whisper API error: "You must provide a model parameter"

Tags: javascript, openai-api, openai-whisper

I am testing a script to convert audio to text. However, while calling the API I am getting an error.

Here is the path I am using

```
  'https://api.openai.com/v1/audio/transcriptions?engine=whisper-1';
```

And the error I am getting is

```
"error": {
        "message": "you must provide a model parameter",
        "type": "invalid_request_error",
        "param": null,
        "code": null
    }
```

I have tried `model=whisper-1` and `model=davinci-002`, both of them are raising the same error. Is there anything that I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the official [OpenAI documentation](https://platform.openai.com/docs/api-reference/audio).

[image: Screenshot]

If you want to use the Whisper API, note the following:

1. Correct API endpoint: `https://api.openai.com/v1/audio/transcriptions`
2. There are two required parameters:

   - `file`
   - `model`

Try this:

```
fetch('https://api.openai.com/v1/audio/transcriptions', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer sk-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
  },
  body: {
    file: 'YOUR_AUDIO_FILE.mp3',
    model: 'whisper-1',
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `'https://api.openai.com/v1/audio/transcriptions'` as the url.
And the model is assigned in the request body:

```js
fetch('https://api.openai.com/v1/audio/transcriptions', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer <Your token>'
  },
  body: {
    model: 'whisper-1',
    file: <Your audio file>,
  }
});
```